# Why do I get this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key when my keys match everywhere?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift5

I keep getting an error message. I've looked through similar questions on google, and they talk about something having to do the storyboard and outlets. Whenever I set my title directly with `self.navigation.title = ___`, i don't get an issue. It's only when I used using `setValuesForKeys(dictionary)`

```
exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FirebaseApp.User 0x600001558940> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.'
```

I have a NSObject with the following. The values are written exactly how I have them on firebase.

```
class User: NSObject {

    var email: String!
    var photoURL: String!
    var username: String!

class MessageController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()


        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("users/profile").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot)
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
//            self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["username"] as? String

                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.setUpNavBar(user: user)

            }
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

    func setUpNavBar(user: User) {
        self.navigationItem.title = user.username
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
class User: NSObject {
    var email: String!
    var photoURL: String!
    var username: String!
}
```

to

```
class User: NSObject {
    @objc var email: String!
    @objc var photoURL: String!
    @objc var username: String!
}
```

or (as Rob says)

```
@objcMembers
class User: NSObject {
    var email: String!
    var photoURL: String!
    var username: String!
}
```

Key-value coding is Objective-C. Objective-C can't see what you don't show it.